# C++ access component via [""] or [int] for custom class

Tags: c++

I've noticed things like what follows in C++.

```
SomeClass obj = SomeClass();
int boo = obj["foo"];
```

What is this called and how can I do it?

example

```
class Boo {
public:
     int GetValue (string item) {
          switch (item) {
               case "foo" : return 1;
               case "apple" : return 2;
          }
          return 0;
     }
}

Boo boo = Boo();
int foo = boo.GetValue("foo");
// instead of that I want to be able to do
int foo = boo["foo"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `[]`, you'd overload `operator[]`:

```
class Boo {
public:
     int operator[](string const &item) {
          if (item == "foo")
              return 1;
          if (item == "apple")
              return 2;
          return 0;
     }
};
```

You might be interested to know `std::map` already provides pretty much what you seem to be looking for:

```
std::map<std::string, int> boo;

boo["foo"] = 1;
boo["apple"] = 2;

int foo = boo["foo"];
```

The obvious difference is that when/if you use this to look up a value that hasn't previously been inserted, it'll insert a new item with that key and the value 0.

Comment: You can't switch on a string.

Answer (score 2):

This is called operator overloading.
You need to define how the operator `[]` works:

```
#include <string>

class Boo {
public:
     int operator[] (std::string item) {
          if (item == "foo")  return 1;
          else if (item == "apple") return 2;
          return 0;
     }
};
Boo boo = Boo();
int foo = boo["foo"];
```

Also, the switch variable must have integral type so I changed to if else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overload the [] operator. [Here is an example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0200__Operator-Overloading/Overloadoperatorforclass.htm) (oddly on a Java site).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is overloading the subscript operator (`operator[]`); in your case you would do:

```
class Boo {
public:
     int operator[](const string & item) const {
          // you can't use switch with non-integral types
          if(item=="foo")
              return 1;
          else if(item=="apple")
              return 2;
          else
              return 0;
     }
}

Boo boo = Boo();
int foo = boo["foo"];
```

Often classes that encapsulate containers return the data by reference, to allow the caller to modify the stored data; that's what most STL containers that provide `operator[]` do.